# How to add published date in product

Tags: date, publish

I have on my site some products. My plan is to show some deals. But I want to show also the published date of the deal, the date that i have published the deal. Like a blogpost shows the published date.

What code can i use and where can i add it?

Hope you can help me. The site is www.vakantie.guru, under accomodation there are some products where i refer to.

I have tried to find in the other files which cope is used for the blogpost date, thought that same code could be used. But I can't find it in the files

Comment: What have you tried? What *exact* problem are you having? Please [edit your question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/344967/edit) to include any relevant code.

Comment: I have tried to find in the other files which cope is used for the blogpost date, thought that same code could be used. But I can't find it in the files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$post_id = 12;
echo get_the_date( 'Y-m-d',$post_id);
```

Comment: It's not a post, it's a product. Can this still be done as you mentioned?

Comment: please use product id instead of post id

Comment: Do I need to put the code in backend of the product or the php of the product?

Comment: in product.php (code where you want to show)

Comment: So i have done it, but i see the code on frontend. Doesn't work :(

Comment: can you show me the code

Comment: $product_id = 12;
echo get_the_date( 'Y-m-d',$product_id);

Comment: https://www.vakantie.guru/kruisherenhotel-maastricht-24-08-19-tot-24-08-19/ please check, I have added the code in the file. right top

Comment: please add it in php tag <?php $product_id = 12; echo get_the_date( 'Y-m-d',$product_id);  ?>

Comment: Yes its visable now, but date is not correct. How can i change it?

Comment: it is the actual date of that productt published. go to product edit page and update. Then check in the frontend

Comment: or use<?php  echo $post->post_modified; ?>

Comment: <?php echo $product->product_modified; ?>        Behind the previous code?

Comment: or use<?php echo $post->post_modified; ?>  or you have to change the date from product edit page

Comment: Yes thats correct, but the date order i can't change in the code. Here we use day-month-year. Also I want to add text in front of the date: Deal published on...  How do i need to tweak the code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97376/discussion-between-anushka27-and-wordpress-dev).

Comment: <?php echo 'Deal published on '.get_the_modified_date( 'Y-m-d',$post->ID); ?>